# I'm coding a mini game in Python, I want to quit my program but I can't

Tags: python, pygame

I need your help, I wanted to make a mini python game with the python module, so far everything was going well, my program opens fine, plays a little music but I can't quit it This, I don't understand (I'm a beginner in python). Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygame  # importation bibliotheque pygame
from pygame.locals import *  # importation de tout les modules de pygame

pygame.init()  # initialisation du module
fen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))  # variable fenetre stockant les valeurs ouvrant cette fenetre en 800 sur 600
pygame.mixer.music.load(r"C:\Users\namik\Music\02 Chun Li.mp3")  # outil de pygame chargeant ma musique
pygame.mixer.music.play()  # lance musique au démarrage du programme
pygame.display.set_caption('clic souris')

running = True  # attribution de la valeur Vrai a running

while True:  # tant que vrai
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/docs/

Comment: You are waiting for a QUIT event, the quit event is probably never occurring. The QUIT event might be emitted when the user tries to close a window.

Comment: Also the answer from @Abhishek seems to be correct in that you not using the running variable in the loop to terminate it.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting running to `False` but the loop will still run since you have it running `while True`. You instead want:

```py
#...
running = True

while running: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
#...
```

So it will terminate when running is set to False.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a common mistake that many beginners make while learning pygame. It seems as though you have put yourself in a loop! Your while loop will run unless the condition it is set to becomes False, but if you put `True` next to it, it will always run! Therefore you will not be able to quit your program. However if you want the while loop to quit when running=False, replace `True` with `running`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygame  # importation bibliotheque pygame
from pygame.locals import *  # importation de tout les modules de pygame

pygame.init()  # initialisation du module
fen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))  # variable fenetre stockant les valeurs ouvrant cette fenetre en 800 sur 600
pygame.mixer.music.load(r"C:\Users\namik\Music\02 Chun Li.mp3")  # outil de pygame chargeant ma musique
pygame.mixer.music.play()  # lance musique au démarrage du programme
pygame.display.set_caption('clic souris')

running = True  # attribution de la valeur Vrai a running

while running:  # tant que vrai
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

This works because while loops stop when their condition becomes false, so by setting `running` to be the condition, whenever `running` becomes false, the while loop stops.

Hope anything I said helps, Thanks!